# How do I close all open tabs in Chrome browser for the iPad?

Tags: ipad, google-chrome

Is there a shortcut for closing all the open tabs in Chrome browser on an iPad?  Last time I checked, which has been a few years now, this function was available on the iPhone, but not on an iPad.

Is this still true?  If so, why is it still missing after so many years?  I can't imagine a technical obstacle to implementing this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the upper right-hand corner of Chrome for iPad is a square with a number in it. That number is the number of tabs open.

1. Single click the square-with-number.
2. It’ll open a “tab overview” page.
3. In the upper left hand corner of the “tab overview” page is a “close all” button.
4. Clicking that button will close all tabs.

1/30/22 - no more box with number.  Up in those teeny icons right at the top, there is a sideways smile emoticon.  Tap it.  The prompt to close all tabs comes up.  Do it!

Comment: LOL!  They just added this feature in the last update. Believe it or not, this feature didn't exist on the iPad for several years, but did exist on the iPhone version!  Yup, a billion dollar company didn't think it was an important enough feature.

Comment: @ATL_DEV I believe it. I don't see any square with a number in it on the upper right-hand corner of Chrome for iPad. Does anyone have any screenshot or  the Chrome version that they use where it works?

Comment: If thee is more than 99 tabs open it is square with smiley instead of square square with number.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the tabs icon in the upper right corner of Chrome -it looks like two sheets of paper. Tap and hold the icon. An option comes up to Close All X Tabs. Select that and they all close. Enjoy! -Kent

Comment: I see a 4 square icon, but not anything like two sheets of paper.  When I click and hold, it just takes me to the tab screen with no option for closing all windows. Are we talking about the iPad?  If so, please attach a screenshot.

Comment: Same here, nothing looks like two sheets of paper. And holding on the 4-square icon doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  There is no sideways smile or "Close All" button.  Just need to suck it up and tap the X on each window displayed... Chrome and Apple, come on now, get it together!